# Is "FileHandling.copyFile" a deprecated method in Java 1.4?

Tags: jsp

I am trying to migrate an old Servlet and JSP application onto a new server, and I'm getting an error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [100] in the jsp file: [/delete.jsp]
FileHandling cannot be resolved
97:     if (fileRef.exists())
98:     {
99:         strServletAction = "deleted";
100:            FileHandling.copyFile(THIS_LOCATION + strTargetFile, ARCHIVE_LOCATION + strFileName);
101:            fileRef.delete();                 // delete file from disc
102:    }else{
103:        strServletAction = "not found";
```

Is this from a package that has gone missing, or is it just deprecated?
The serlvet is supposed to be running against J2SDK1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it turns out that this was a utility method from a supporting class, my real problem was that the import statement isn't picking up  `utils.class`
I only needed one function so I just copy/pasted it into the JSP file.